# XCOPY and VS 2013 Post-Build Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, copy, xcopy

As much as this topic has been talked about, I would think that someone else has run into the same issue as me and found a solution.

This XCOPY Script works in another environment using VS 2012 (with macros) and the same environment using the command line.

> XCOPY "C:\Web.Forms\bin\Web.Forms.dll" "C:\inetpub\WebSite\bin" /Y /R
>
> XCOPY "C:\Web.Forms\UserControls\*.ascx" "C:\inetpub\WebSite\usercontrols" /Y /R

It keeps throwing an error of 4 and does not copy within VS 2013. If I change it to "COPY" I get an error of 1.  For the purpose of testing and to use it in the command line I stripped it of all Macro's.  Actually, I used the [macro] generated directory strings from the error message successfully in the command line.

So why doesn't this work in Visual Studio 2013? VS is running as Administrator.

Comment: Show the actual post-build commands, not what you think it got translated to.

Comment: I'm not guessing at anything. This is what I placed into Visual Studio and it failed. This is what I placed into the command prompt and it ran successfully. Hence, not an XCOPY issue or directory issue.

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30780395/2020827) workaround.